# Setting up HSTS on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, hsts

Im about to set up HSTS on via CloudFlare on my AWS Beanstalk application. I have:

1) Created a Certificate using AWS Certificate Manager and applied to the load balancer (and set HTTPS listener port to 443)

2) Switched CloudFlare SSL to FULL (from previously being set to Flexible)

I am about to switch on CloudFlare HSTS, however, the following considerations are mentioned:

*"One critical consideration when using HSTS on Cloudflare is that once HSTS is turned on, your website must continue to have a valid HTTPS configuration conforming with the HSTS header to avoid making the website inaccessible to users. If SSL is disabled through other means (“grey clouding” a Flexible SSL website, or moving a website off Cloudflare), it is possible the website will be inaccessible to users for the duration of cached max-age headers, or until HTTPS is re-established and an HSTS header with value 0 is served. Consequently, HSTS configuration requires reading and acknowledging understanding of a warning message."*

So, this has me a little freaked: I am not intending to turn off SSL at anytime. I will probably not quit CloudFlare either. But, what is something should get messed up when i turn it on? Will I be able to just turn off HSTS again and go "Phew, that was close" or am I screwed?

/Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that you always use HTTPS. So if you ditch Cloudflare you need to ensure that a SSL certificate is properly installed on your server.

It will only effect users that have visited your site before as the browser caches it. If they clear their cache etc they can visit again.

I have create a guide here which will covers off any issues you might face: https://www.engaging.io/how-to-easily-configure-hsts-for-super-secure-ssl/